# Upload example not working in PHP uploader class

Tags: php, file-upload

I was just trying out the examples at PHP uploader **[HERE](https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader)**. I tried the upload example below:

include('../src/class.uploader.php');

```
$uploader = new Uploader();
$data = $uploader->upload('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png', array(
    'uploadDir' => 'uploads/', //Upload directory {String}
    'title' => array('auto', 10), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
));

if($data['isComplete']){
    $files = $data['data'];
    print_r($files);
}

if($data['hasErrors']){
    $errors = $data['errors'];
    print_r($errors);
}
```

I have the the above script and the dependency `class.uploader.php` on my server , all in the right directory , now when i run `upload.php` , the image file is not uploaded at all , I.E. when i open the `uploads` directory in the same folder as `upload.php`, i see no image file uploaded . Why is that ??

Comment: Is that a local file? If not that might be your issue...

Comment: @nerdlyist what is a local file ??

Comment: Actually nvm. Are you looking in the right directory? I just downloaded the src and ran the example from above and works like a charm.

Comment: @nerdlyist , so heres what i did , i downloaded the files from github , now i upoaded it to my server , then i create a folder `\uploads` , then visited the url where where my upload.php file and hit enter in the url bar , now when i visit my uploads directory i don't see any image uploaded :(